# How to customize date format of SimpleDateFormat() in Java (android)?

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

In my PHP webpage, I used this code (given below), which gives me the day's date in my desired format, which is (example) **2nd Oct. 2021**.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo date('jS M\. Y'); //result = 2nd Oct. 2021
?>
```

Now, I want to achieve the same with Java - when I tried adding the format `jS M\. Y` in Java (android), it showed me some errors I'm unable to understand... Here's what I've tried in Java -

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("jS M\. Y", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

I am currently new to Java & just found out about this class, so I don't know a lot of things  What should I do in order to get the day's date in my desired format? Please guide me... Thanks!

Comment: Refer to _javadoc_ for class [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) However, if your java version is compatible with at least Java 8, it is recommended to work with the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ordinalMap())
                                .appendPattern(" MMM. uuuu")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        String output = date.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    static Map<Long, String> ordinalMap() {
        String[] suffix = { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th" };
        Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
            map.put((long) i, String.valueOf(i) + suffix[(i > 3 && i < 21) ? 0 : (i % 10)]);

        return map;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2nd Oct. 2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/CHxpzq)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

#### Update

A valuable comment from [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer):

> Since this is tagged as Android, it should be noted that `java.time` is
> available [in Android since 8.0 (Oreo)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary) and most of it can be accessed
> even when targeting older versions [through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Since this is tagged as Android, it should be noted that `java.time` is available [in Android since 8.0 (Oreo)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary) and most of it can be accessed even when targeting older versions [through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: Thanks, @JoachimSauer for the valuable information. I've incorporated it into my answer because sometimes comments get deleted.

Comment: Thanks @ArvindKumarAvinash! Your approach works perfectly for me - you're the best! Thanks a lot again 

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy your requirements?

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```